# Visual Studio Extension Build Solution error 0x

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fatal-error, visual-studio-extensions, envdte, rebuild

I have this code for clean, build and run solution as Visual Studio Extension

```
Dim dte As DTE = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"))
Dim sb As SolutionBuild = dte.Solution.SolutionBuild
sb.Clean(True) ' here
sb.Build(True) ' here too
sb.Run() ' here too
```

but when I run it it throws on clean or build or run command fatal error 0x8000FFFF

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

stack trace is

```
   at EnvDTE.SolutionBuild.Clean(Boolean WaitForCleanToFinish)
   at VSIXProject1.Command1.MenuItemCallback(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Projects\_VSAddins\VSIXProject1\VSIXProject1\Command1.vb:line 84
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.MenuCommand.Invoke()
   at System.ComponentModel.Design.MenuCommand.Invoke(Object arg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.OleMenuCommandService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& commandGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& guidGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdExcept, IntPtr pIn, IntPtr vOut)
```

Why? how to repair it?

Comment: Where are you calling this from? I could imagine that would fail if you already had a build active, called it from the wrong thread, etc...

Comment: I want to create custom command which will call "Rebuild all" and then "Run". I am doing this because when I press debug button, Visual Studio do not call "rebuild all" but only "rebuild" command and Visual Studio often skip build some projects (but I need it). My idea is to create VSIX which define new command which will call "Rebuild all" and then "Run" command. I call it in MenuItemCallback of Command.

Comment: If you need to invoke a build of all projects instead of just your projects needed for F5, there's just an option under Tools > Options to change this behavior. If you need it to actually *clean* every time, then something tells me your real question here is "how do I fix my solution so I don't have to do that?".